# How to compare two records in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have created a stored procedure which joins data from various tables and returns a result set in temporary table.

Now when I update the record from the GUI, I want only those fields in my UI to show up which are changed. And the rest of the columns should remain blank since they were not edited.

How can I make change in my stored procedure such that it returns only the edited fields from second time onwards?

Comment: You don't use the same Sproc, for one thing.

Comment: You need to provide a lot more information if you want some help.

Comment: Which GUI are you using?  Most have some sort of OldValue property for their textboxes which will allow you to determine whether the value was changed.

Comment: I am using a stored procedure to get data from various tables. it shows a record in UI. Then I edit the data and it shows the previous and the new changed record. My client asked me to show only the column that I have edited and not all the data from table again. As it becomes difficult for them to spot the change.

Comment: I am just using a template architecture for UI. rest data is populated from back end(SQL server)

Comment: The question may make a lot of sense to you, but we know nothing about your project or the data.  Without seeing some table fields, sample data or anything else, we're flying blind.  I, for one, have no idea if your data is all one-to-one or if there are one-to-many relationships, or what makes the data records unique.  You need to edit your question and be overly verbose.  Too much information is always better than too little information, especially when you're asking for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

think about using unpivot for each table 
and compare the result by identity and fields name
[Using PIVOT and UNPIVOT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx)